# Testing interactions in simulated data

Tags: r, logistic

I have some simulated data and wish to test for interactions. There are 500 predictors (0, 1 or 2) and a binary outcome variable. Predictor 101 and 424 are simulated to interact multiplicative. The data is in the object 'dataMatrix' in which each predictor is called "Xn" (n : 1-500) and the binary outcome is called 'Phenotype'. I test the interaction by fitting the predictors to the outcome variable using logistic regression and including an interaction term for the specific pairwise interaction as such,

```
model <- glm(Phenotype ~ . + X101*X424, data=dataMatrix, family = "binomial")
s <- as.data.frame(summary(model)$coefficients)
s[dim(s)[1], ]
```

I have simulated 3 data sets with pairwise interactions (101, 424), (10, 50) & (200, 500). The interaction terms are below:

```
          Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)
X101:X424  0.34597  0.1866066 1.854008 0.06373804
         Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)
X10:X50 0.3210071  0.1780819 1.802581 0.07145408
           Estimate Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)
X200:X500 -1.509658   1.161329 -1.29994 0.1936215
```

I was expecting to see interaction terms of higher value and with significant p-values. Therefore I am in doubt if I am using the correct approach. Is this the correct way of testing for interactions or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: First of all, your way of specifying the interaction seems fine. For anything further, I think you'd need to provide details on how the data were simulated. Fitting a model with 500 predictors in a useful fashion will generally require a lot of data. Multicollinearity might be one issue. The size of the interaction effect could be another issue. Finally, note that predictors in logistic regression are assumed to be either binary or metric, while yours seem to be categorical.

Comment: @fujiu Most of your advice is accurate, but please note that (1) Logistic regression makes no assumptions about the measurement type of the explanatory variables and will work with any type. (2) The example output shows these variables `x10`, `x50`, etc. are numerical and not categorical.